# Character texture is messed up

Tags: modeling, texturing, game-engine, uv

[image: The Overall Result]

As you can see above, that is my character, I modeled him, textured him, rigged him, used GLSL texturing, in the game engine, pressed "P," and he looked like this. I don't know what this is, is it transparent, I don't know? Please help!

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your textures. I'm not familiar with the game engine though. :-/

Comment: This looks like a depth problem, can you share the file.

Comment: Yeah, you need to bring that "patient" to us. :)

Comment: I think your material is set to alpha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 99% certain that your normals are inverted. Try the following with each object:

-Select the object and tab into edit mode

-Select all of the vertices

-Use the Mesh menu to select Mesh->Normals->Recalculate Outside

Alternatively, you can select a face in edit mode and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to "flip normals." This will just reverse whatever direction it already is, so it's not quite and handy, but it might be helpful if the first method doesn't work.

The actual problem is that polygons only have one side. If they're viewed from the "wrong" side, they are completely invisible. So, you have to make sure that the visible side is facing out, not in. The "normal" is the vector that points straight out from the surface of the visible side. So, recalculating the normals so they face outside will make it look right.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried both ideas but that 1% was it, your solution didn't work, sorry.

Comment: Well... I can't go any further... you must finish the journey without me... Good luck ;-)

Comment: God dangit!?!?!

Comment: If you can upload your file, there are some other folks who seem to be willing to look at it (I'm at work, so I can't download stuff, or I'd look at it). It's not safe to go alone... take this: pasteall.org

Comment: I've noticed my problem, there was a small issue with the textures that had to be fixed, and it was not the alpha, sorry @Cobra that wasn't it, but on the bright side I am done with this problem. Now ill recreate one with better textures and enjoy him. Thanks all!